# Difference Between Musics Fans Beta and Musics: Practice & Theory

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

So I've been wanted to join a Stack site pertaining to playing Guitar, Bass, and Banjo and where I can get help learning how to improve technique and get assistance in making TABS for popular songs, particularly for Banjo as it's the least accessible of the three instruments I play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Music Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) is a site for "musicians, students, and enthusiasts". This is the place to go if you have a question on how to play music, a specific question about music theory, etc.

[Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour) is a site for "music historians, critics, and fans". This is more for things like history of music, song identification, etc.

Because you're asking about techniques for playing music and assistance in making TABS, you should ask on Music Practice and Theory.

Comment: Song identification appears to have been made off-topic on Music Fans SE: see [Identification Questions are now off-topic. Here's our next steps](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/733) on [musicfans.meta.se].

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to play music, you want [Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/).